# Spock stubbing RestTemplate method

Tags: spring-boot, testing, resttemplate, spock, stub

I'm trying to write tests for my client class, which uses `RestTemplate` to get files from my cloud (`getSingleFileContentMap()` method).

This is the full code of the client class:

```groovy
package i18n.translationbundle.client;

import i18n.configuration.TranslationProperties;
import i18n.translationbundle.TranslationBundle;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

    @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
        public class DotCMSClient implements TranslationBundleSupplier {

            private final TranslationProperties translationProperties;
            private final RestTemplate template;

            @Override
            public TranslationBundle getTranslationBundle(String language) {
                Set<Map<String, String>> set = getTranslationsSetForLanguage(language);
                return new TranslationBundle(
                        set.stream()
                                .flatMap(x -> x.entrySet().stream())
                                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                                        Map.Entry::getValue,
                                        (v1, v2) -> v2
                                )));
            }

            private Set<Map<String, String>> getTranslationsSetForLanguage(String language) {
                return translationProperties.getResourceUrls()
                        .get(language)
                        .values()
                        .stream()
                        .map(this::getSingleFileContentMap)
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
            }

            private Map<String, String> getSingleFileContentMap(String location) {
                String domainAddress = translationProperties.getSourceDomain();
                return template.exchange(domainAddress + location, HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){}).getBody();
            }

        }
```

My goal is to stub the `getSingleFileContent()` in my tests, so I won't have to rely on the connection. These are two ways how I've tried to stub it:

```groovy
client.getSingleFileContentMap("dashboard") >> mapper.readValue(
            dashboardJson,
            new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){})
```

and

```groovy
template.exchange("src/test/resources/en-us/dashboard.lang.json", HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){}) >>
            mapper.readValue(
                    dashboardJson,
                    new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){})
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
client.getSingleFileContentMap("dashboard")
|      |
|      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
<translationbundle.client.DotCMSClient@b978d10 translationProperties=TranslationProperties(sourceDomain=, fileNames=null, languages=[en-us], resourceUrls={en-us={dashboard=src/test/resources/en-us/dashboard.lang.json, ip-block=src/test/resources/en-us/ip-block.lang.json, general=src/test/resources/en-us/general.lang.json}}) template=org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate@2ce6c6ec>
```

What am I doing wrong? Isn't stubbing supposed to blindly return what I want, without intervening into the methods implementation? Here, it seems that it's still running `getSingleFileContentMap()` the way it was implemented in the client class code. I understand that stubbing `Rest Template`'s `exchange()` method might not work, but why doesn't it work with `getSingleFileContentMap()`?

Comment: Nobody can copy and compile your class (which is not copmplete as you say because imports and package are missing) because a lot of dependencies are missing, so I can only speculate until you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The first thing that strikes me is that in your first try to stub `getSingleFileContentMap("dashboard")` you want to return a `String` but the method has a return type of `Map<String, String>`. So how about actually returning something that fits the return type? ;-) BTW, stubbing a private method looks bad, maybe you want to refactor your code.

Comment: I've updated the class with proper imports and fixed the stubs

Comment: Thanks, Jack. I still cannot compile + run your client class because your own classes `TranslationProperties` and `TranslationBundle` are missing, but you use them in your code. The test is also incomplete, I have no idea how you define variables such as `client`, `mapper`, `dashboardJson`. A GitHub repository with a complete, minimal project + build would be helpful. Too many moving targets, too much speculation here.

Comment: How did you mock your RestTemplate ?, it seems that you are using a real one or a Spy